# Реализация умного поиска. Нужны идеи

Tags: api, поиск, amazon

Есть задача по реализации умного и сильного поиска. Единственный и самый большой минус в том что у нас нету БД и мы подключены к API Amazon и Ebay и к тому же все поисковые запросы само самой должны быть на английском что бы наши API сервисы выводили результат.

И так нам нужно что бы пользователь который делает поисковой запрос на русском то запрос  бы перевелся на английский, если на английском делает запрос то так и оставить.

Пробовал через API гугл транслейт, переводит просто ужасно, где 50% поисковых запросов не правильно переводятся.

Comment: А сам вопрос в чём?